# Installing Python module within code and running from ArcGIS Pro script tool?

Tags: arcpy, installation, arcgis-pro, import, python-script-tool

I am trying to install a third-party Python package from within a Python script so that other users can run the script and the package can be installed and loaded without having to manually download and install.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import subprocess

def install(package):
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", 'pip', 'install', package])

install('pyodbc')
import pyodbc
```

This seems to work fine from within my stand-alone Python script. However, when I try to run it as a script tool set up in ArcGIS Pro, it is not finding the installed package and is failing with this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

Do I need to change a path or environment setting?

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS Pro? Things changed at 2.2 in regards to the Python environment and Conda. I'd read: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm

Comment: I'm actually still on 2.1.3. I have not upgraded to 2.2 yet. But, this is helpful for understanding the package manager better.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm looking to do the same in Pro 2.3.1

Comment: From within ArcGIS Pro, `sys.executable` will not point to a `python.exe`, it will point to `arcgispro.exe`, which will not understand the command line flags intended for `pip`. You will have to import pip and use it as shown in gis-professional's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your python code, you can install a package using

```
import pip

pip.main(['install','package-name'])
```

Write this at top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.3.1 at least, you can install packages by going to "Python" in the starting menu and clicking "Add Packages". (I checked, 'pyodbc' is in the list of available packages.) This feature may be new, I haven't been using arcGIS for very long.

conda install is also a good option, if what you're looking for isn't in the list of available packages in the Package Manager. Just make sure you've got the right environment.